# Why the operator equal is not converting null obtained from valueOf() to zero?

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

In the last line, I know that a.valueOf() is called because the operands are not of the same type. Knowing that null converts to zero, why a browser would not convert null to zero and return false at the end?

```
function A(){}
A.prototype.valueOf = function(){return null}
var a = new A
a == null // => This is always false
a == 0 // => true or false depending on the browser you are using.
```

Comment: WTH do you mean by "*true, sometimes false*"? It's *always* `false`.

Comment: You're getting different values using chrome or firefox right?

Comment: That is right. In Firefox I am getting true.

Comment: If I replace "return null" to "return "0"", than I get true all the time. It seems that "0" is converted to a number, but null is not for some reason.

Comment: I was able to isolate the difference between Chrome and Firefox. When Firefox convert an Object to null it convert null to zero. Chrome does not covert null to zero and and try the comparison again using null not zero. I still don't know why Firefox does that, something left undefined in the JS5 documentation perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that valueOf() is used because the operands are not of the same type

Not in general "when they are not of the same type", no. `ToPrimitive` (and subsequently `[[DefaultValue]]` and `.valueOf`) are only called when comparing either a Boolean, Number, or String to an Object.

> null converts to zero

Yes, when `ToNumber` is called upon it. It for example doesn't when `ToString` is called.

> Why a browser would not convert null to zero and return false at the end?

Because `null` and `0` are different primitive types for which no conversion is specified in the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3), no `ToNumber` is called. They simply are not equal, point.

In Firefox however, there is [a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1132045) with this.

Comment: If they are not equal why some browsers return true at the end?

Comment: @user148098: Which browsers return `true`? They are wrong, or implement a different language. This has not changed with ES6. Maybe some implementor confused `Type()` with `typeof`.

Comment: Firefox35.0.1 Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu

Comment: ToNumber is called in Firefox and Firefox does not  implement a different language. Maybe the specification left some cases open and implementations are free to make their choice, or Firefox interpreted the specification in a different way, or Firefox choose not to follow the specification.

Comment: So Firefox does not follow the specification. Would you kindly update your answer to clarify that if the interpreted evaluates to true, than it does not follow the specification?